# Second gtk_main_quit() not working

Tags: rust, gtk

In an application, I nest gtk event loops to be able to return a value in a callback.
However, I have some issues with a callback already calling `gtk_main_quit()` because multiple calls to this function does not seem to exit as many nestings of event loop.

Here is an example of my issue:

```
extern crate gtk;

use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;
use std::thread;

use gtk::{Button, ButtonExt, ContainerExt, Continue, Inhibit, WidgetExt, Window, WindowType};

fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap();
    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);

    let quit = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

    window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
        gtk::main_quit();
        Inhibit(false)
    });

    let button = Button::new_with_label("Click");
    let quit2 = quit.clone();
    button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
        let quit = quit2.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            quit.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        });
        println!("Run");
        gtk::main();
    });
    window.add(&button);
    window.show_all();

    gtk::idle_add(move || {
        if quit.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            println!("Quit");
            gtk::main_quit();
            gtk::main_quit();
            quit.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
        }
        Continue(true)
    });

    gtk::main();
}
```

As you can see in the `gtk::idle_add` call, I call `gtk::main_quit()` twice, which should exit the application when the button is pressed because `gtk::main()` was also called twice (one at the end of the `main` function, the other one in the button clicked callback).
But the application does not exit when I click the button.

The documentation of gtk seems to indicate that this is the expected behaviour:

> Makes the innermost invocation of the main loop return **when it regains control**.

(emphasis is mine)

So, I believe that this does not exit the application because calling `gtk::main_quit()` twice won't allow the gtk main loop to "regain control".

My question is, what should I do between the two calls to `gtk::main_quit()` to stop the 2 nestings of event loop?

Comment: Calling `gtk_main_quit()` twice in a row like that has no effect because only the innermost `gtk_main()` will be marked for quitting — and it's merely marked for quitting, so you need to return to `gtk_main()` to actually quit for real. Hence, the only way to make the second `gtk_main_quit()` quit the way you expect it is to put it after the inner `gtk_main()` returns. However, I don't fully understand what the goal of your code is, especially since your use of `gtk_main()` and `gtk::idle_add()` is unusual, so I don't feel like I can properly answer the question yet. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That was actually only an example. My real code is quite complex so that's why I didn't posted it. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to ask the user whether to exit or not when the window is closed. This is asked with a nested event loop because I need to prevent from closing the window if the user doesn't want to exit. In case the user wants to exit, `gtk::main_quit()` is called twice (not 2 instructions in a row like in this question, but the effect is the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue by manually creating a glib `MainLoop` and using it instead of nesting calls gtk event loop.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: the solution is to replace the second `gtk::main_quit` with:

```
gtk::idle_add(|| {
    gtk::main_quit();
    Continue(false)
});
```

As before, the first `gtk::main_quit()` will arrange for the inner main loop to quit. Additionally, the idle handler will be picked up by the *outer* main loop, causing it to immediately terminate as well.

This can be generalized with a pseudo-recursive function that repeats the process as many times as necessary:

```
fn deep_main_quit(n: usize) {
    if n == 0 {
        return;
    }
    gtk::main_quit();
    gtk::idle_add(move || {
        deep_main_quit(n - 1);
        Continue(false)
    });
}
```

Note that the use of `idle_add` to continually check for a flag will result in busy-looping, which you almost certainly want to avoid. (On my machine, running your program takes up a full CPU core.) In general, the preferred approach is to wait on a condition variable. But if you just need to tell the GUI thread to do something, as shown in your code, you can just call `glib::idle_add` from a different thread. The provided callback will be queued and executed in the GUI thread.

With this change, one thread releasing two levels of `gtk_main` in the GUI thread would look like this:

```
fn main() {
    gtk::init().unwrap();
    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);

    window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
        gtk::main_quit();
        Inhibit(false)
    });

    let button = Button::new_with_label("Click");
    button.connect_clicked(|_| {
        thread::spawn(|| {
            glib::idle_add(|| {
                println!("Quit");
                deep_main_quit(2);
                Continue(false)
            });
        });
        println!("Run");
        gtk::main();
    });
    window.add(&button);
    window.show_all();

    gtk::main();
}
```